# Boolean Operation in Postgres on TIME type columns using Python

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

An SQL table includes a column as the following

```
CREATE TABLE booleantimeoperation (
name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
start_time TIME NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (name)
);
```

Let's say, current time is calculated as:

```
from datetime import datetime
t2 = datetime.time(datetime.now())
```

Using psycopg2, the values extracted from the corresponding column is datetime.time object.

Is it possible to query the table to get entries where time entry is greater or less than t2?

Answer (score 1):

Sure:

```py
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM booleantimeoperation WHERE start_time >= %s;", (t2,))
```

From the documentation: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries